# Tooltip text color bootstrap Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

Trying to change the color of the tooltip text from default to red

[image]

***Payment initiated during night time (00:00 – 06:00)*** needs to be red

Comment: Checked your devtools to find out the class used in the DOM? This is the way to go. Feel free to drop us a [repro] or more context if you want some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add new class if you want or you can use the current same class.
Below is the example where I have used class name as **redtexttooltip**:

Example code:

```
.redtexttooltip + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {color: #f00;}
```

Please check and let me know if you find any issues

Comment: Probably needs a `deep` here, on top of a longshot class name.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get your words